# Placing existing Google Map V3 into a form to change address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm building an application where user-submitted posts are placed via their location as markers on a Google Map. The users are currently able to view the markers/posts on a map in relation to their current location.

What I'm aiming to do is allow the user to change the location of the map so that users can see the markers/posts in relation to another address, specifically via a form that allows them to enter an address and change the location of the map.

I found a YouTube video illustrating a pretty close approximation of what I'm aiming to do, but it unfortunately provides no code or instructions (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uyIawlsvzU).

Is there a way to efficiently wrap an existing Google Map and the existing markers into a form such as this? I've searched for a solution but can't seem to find the proper way to achieve this. Many thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to search for LatLng by user specified address and to display it. I see not problems at all :)
Study [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) for this (seems best solution for your case) and [this example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)